# PowerPoint / PHP - How do I generate non standard custom PowerPoint charts using PowerPoint templates and PHP?

Tags: php, excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to generate a Powerpoint Chart with graphs that are dependent on dynamic data from PHP.

I have tried OpenTBS but it does not recognize the template because it is a pptm (macro enabled) file.

How do I go about dynamically specifying the data to merge with a template that contains complex graphs and macros like below?

Embedded Excel Data

[image: Table]

Chart in PowerPoint slide

[image: Risk]

Sample Color Subroutine in VBA

```
Sub ColorByValue()
        'Assume we have only one slide, at slide 1:
        Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        'Assume the Chart is the second shape, modify if needed
        Set shp = sld.Shapes(2)
        'Handle the chart
        Set cht = shp.Chart
        'Handle the ChartData
        Set chtData = cht.ChartData


      Dim likelihood As Long
      Dim vPatterns As Variant
      Dim consequence As Long
      Dim vValues As Variant
      Dim point As Long

       Set rPatterns = chtData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:F6")

       For likelihood = 1 To 5
       With cht.SeriesCollection(likelihood)
          For consequence = 1 To 5
              .Points(consequence).Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = rPatterns.Cells(likelihood, consequence).Interior.Color
          Next
      End With
      Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried saving your template as a PPT rather than PPTM?

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg for the suggestion.  I unfortunately cannot preserve the file type of ppt when I save using OpenTBS.    It keeps defaulting to pptx.  I am trying to find other solutions to save macro enabled presentations with merged content.

Comment: Modifying my script, causes the ppt to not render even if OpenTBS opens it and saves it as ppt.