# OpenTBS/PHP - How to generate a PowerPoint file with macros?

Tags: php, opentbs

I want to generate a PowerPoint with OpenTBS/PHP with macros enabled in the document.  Is this possible using OpenTBS, and if not are there other tools I can use?

Linked Question below describes my current setup:

[PowerPoint / PHP - What tools allow for generating a data driven merged template (pptx) with embedded macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771946/powerpoint-php-what-tools-allow-for-generating-a-data-driven-merged-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTBS supports PPTM files as well as PPTX.
Nevertheless it cannot work with encrypted documents.

Comment: Does a pptm file with macros mean that it is encrypted?

Comment: PPTM files are not encrypted by default. You can use PPTM template files with OpenTBS the same way you are using PPTX.

Comment: It works now, with latest updates.   Faced with a new problem,  pptm downloaded file when opened (not saved) keeps opening as .pptx causing an error.   When saved and opened, there is no error.  How do I fix this?

Comment: what navigator is causing an error when download this file ?

Comment: Firefox, when I open, it keeps opening as pptx

Comment: What do you mean it is opening as pptx ? A pptm is supposed to be opened the same way as pptx.

Comment: When I save rather than open it opens as pptm.  When I instead open immediately it adds a .pptx extension to the file and PowerPoint cannot open the file.  I get the error "PowerPoint cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.  Verify the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Comment: This is actually a bug in the content-type given to the navigator when downloading the file. The last OpenTBS version 1.9.10 does fix this bug.